# Date format SSRS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In my stored procedure I have the following columns in my output dataset:

```
,   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.trd_ex_eff_tms, 104)         AS [Trade date]

,   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), i.mat_exp_dte, 104)            AS [Maturity date]
```

This returns dates in the following format:  08.05.2015

However when I put this into SSRS in a straight table, when I render the report it shows a date of 08/05/2015?

I haven't applied any formatting on the column in the table, I just wanted to return the text (varchar) of the column which I expected to return the formatting that is setup in the stored procedure.

Am I missing something?  Why does SSRS automatically see this as a date and converts into a date format I don't want?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tested out doing a date conversion as you specify and using in SSRS - it works fine for me and displays in a table with the 8.25.2015 style. That leads me to suspect that there is probably formatting applied to the textbox or placeholder. Take a look at the properties tab and locate Format under the Number section. Clear out any formatting and try again.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this

=Format(Fields!YourDate.Value, "dd.MM.yyyy")